# Which method of combining ratios is ‘better’?

Tags: interactive-teaching

Given that:- (1) a : b = 5 : 24, and (2) b : c = 16 : 7

In getting the combined ratio a : b : c, there are two approaches:-

**Method 1**:

1.1 Rewrite (1) as a : b = 5*16 : 24*16 = 80 : 384

1.2 Rewrite (2) as b : c = 16*24 : 7 * 24 = 384 : 168

1.3 Then a : b : c = … = 80 : 384 : 168

1.4 Reduce the finding by the HCF of (80 : 384 : 168) and get 10 : 48 : 21.

**Method 2**:

2.1 Find the LCM of (24, 16) = 48.

2.2 Rewrite (1) as a : b = 5*(48/24) : 48 = 10 : 48;

2.3 Rewrite (2) as b : c = 48 : 7*(48/16) = 48 : 21.

2.4 The result is a : b : c = 10 : 48 : 21

---

What do you (as a teacher) think by considering more easier to teach? more logical?

From the view of a learner, which is more readily acceptable? more simpler to learn (or understand)?

Other considerations, which is more systematic? more easier to program?
. . .

There is no need to answer this question in a hurry. If you have students of this level, show them both approaches and then ask for their feedback. You probably will be surprised.

Comment: The way that is better is the way that your student can explain *why* it works.

Comment: @Mick your last two sentences seem to imply that you already have some idea of which method is better.  If this is the case, you should probably edit to include your opinion, and your justification.  Then your question will be "Is this supported by your experience as well?", or "Is there any research supporting or refuting this?"

Comment: @StevenGubkin T'is an open question and has no specific right answer. A teacher will probably use method-2 'cause it is more logical in mathematics. T'is especially true when the 'common-value' (in this case, 384=16*24) is even larger that makes cancellation difficult. Hence, method-2 is preferred because the afore-mentioned can be totally avoided. However, as a student, they probably will find method-1 more systematic, easier to understand and to program. You are quite right on your finding but I don’t have the answer. I can only guess it because I have no chance to perform this experiment.

Comment: I think you should consider more closely what @StevenGubkin suggested in order to improve this question. As it stands, it merely sounds like you have a conjecture about what teachers. vs. students prefer when faced with this precise juxtaposition of two methods. It's both an oddly specific question and one that begs for either opinion-based responses or a bunch of informal, non-scientific data gathering. Even if it is that, you should be more straightforward with your conjectures. You have unsupported assumptions about what teachers and students prefer.

Comment: I must also confess that I have never seen this notation before.  Is this common now in elementary math education?

Comment: @StevenGubkin Don’t understand what does “this notation” refer to. Anyway, it is hard to say whether it is a common practice now. I think, as a teacher, he/she should introduce to the students various possible methods that can lead to the solution.

Comment: @JPBurke You are quite right on the assumption is unsupported. That is why I suggest that have the methods tried by the students and ask for their feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never seen that particular type of problem, but the issue you're referring to comes up similarly in adding fractions, a much more common problem type. Given the problem: Find 5/24 + 7/16, we could ask which is better: (1) multiplying the first fraction, top and bottom, by 16, and the second one, top and bottom, by 24, or (2) Realizing that the LCD is 48, and proceeding to get a common denominator of 48 (instead of the huge and unwieldy 384).

I don't know which students prefer. I would expect to work with them on easier problems where both methods make sense (have fractions with denominators of 4 and 6, work the problem both ways), and discuss the pros and cons with the students. I think I would try to slowly ratchet up the difficulty, hoping to get students to agree that method 2 is more sensible.

Of course, many students would argue that their calculator can do this more effectively than we can, whichever method we're trying to use.

Answer (score 4):

JPBurke is correct that the best way is whatever way "that your student can explain *why* it works."

The format of this question may make it difficult for some students to understand.

Here are some basic rules that are needed to solve problems like this:

- You can multiply both sides of a ratio by the same number, and the ratio will still be the same.
- You can divide both sides of a ratio by the same number, and the ratio will still be the same.
- Except -- you cannot divide by zero.
- When in doubt, go step-by-step.
- You can always check your work (Check-By-Substitution, or CBS).

And here are some follow-up lessons:

- All ratios are really fractions in disguise.
- All fractions are really division problems in disguise.

When I saw the problem, I immediately thought of a third way to solve it.

> a : b =  5 : 24, and
>
> b : c = 16 : 7

Reading them out loud, like an old-fashioned SAT analogy problem:

> "a" is to "b" as 5 is to 24.
>
> "b" is to "c" as 16 is to 7.

Why abbreviate the variable names to just one letter?  It is easier to understand a problem if the variables describe things that are understandable.  And if the variables have units, keep the units with the quantities.

> For every 5 apples, there are 24 bananas.
>
> For every 16 bananas, there are 7 cucumbers.
>
> For every 24 bananas, there are how many cucumbers?

Notice that:

> 24 = 16 * (3/2).
>
> For every 16 * (3/2) bananas, there are 7 * (3/2) cucumbers.
>
> For every 24 bananas, there are 10 1/2 cucumbers.
>
> For every 5 apples, there are 24 bananas, and 10 1/2 cucumbers.

Multiplying through by 2 gets rid of the fraction:

> For every 10 apples, there are 48 bananas, and 21 cucumbers.

The greatest common denominator of 10, 48, and 21 is 1, so we do not need to simplify any further.  The answer is:

> a : b : c = 10 : 48 : 21
>
> "a" is to "b" is to "c" as 10 is to 48 is to 21.

Check-By-Substitution:

> Is 10 : 48 the same ratio as 5 : 24?
>
> Yes.  2 * 5 : 2 * 24 is the same ratio as 5 : 24.
>
> Is 48 : 21 the same ratio as 16 : 7?
>
> Yes.  3 * 16 : 3 * 7 is the same ratio as 16 : 7.